# Global Plugins in Gradle

Tags: plugins, gradle

I am using Gradle as a build tool for my Scala projects. I am also using Eclipse for development, so I always use the `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` in my build files.

Is there also a way to define the `apply plugin` globally? SBT already has [such a feature](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Using-Plugins). The reason why I want this, is that other developers who’re using my project probably don’t use Eclipse but another IDE and they would have to change the build script for their needs. If there were a global configuration file, one could put personal configurations in there and it wouldn’t conflict other ones.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is... if other users don't use Eclipse then they don't run `gradle eclipse`.  You can add the other plugin (for IDEA) also and they can use that if they want.  As I understand it, `apply` just makes the plugin available.  It doesn't force all users to use it.

Comment: Well, that’s right. Never thought about it this way. I’m coming from SBT and missed this feature. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put this into `~/.gradle/init.gradle`:

```
rootProject.allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
}
```

The drawback of this approach is that it makes the build less reproducible. People now need to add something to their `init.gradle` to make (some aspect of) the build work. Therefore, I would recommend to apply the Eclipse plugin in the main build script; it won't hurt people who don't use it.

Comment: This should now just be: `rootProject { apply plugin: "eclipse" }`

Comment: For multi-project builds, the `eclipse` plugin must be applied to all projects.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser What if it's a third party plugin that doesn't come with gralde and needs to be added to the classpath. Can init.gradle still be used this way?

Comment: Using `rootProject.allprojects` fails for me with "The root project is not yet available for build."; just `rootProject` works (in a single-project build).

Answer (score 0):

for the accepted answer, I also got the error message "The root project is not yet available for build".

I am using gradle 7.6 and I was trying to use the [Gradle Test Logger Plugin](https://github.com/radarsh/gradle-test-logger-plugin)

Here's the `~/.gradle/init.gradle` that worked for me:

```
initscript {
  repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.adarshr:gradle-test-logger-plugin:3.2.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
  apply plugin: com.adarshr.gradle.testlogger.TestLoggerPlugin
}
```

There are multiple things to be aware of when configuring a 3rd party plugin globally:

- you need to add the plugin as a dependency to make it available
- you need to reference the plugin by its implementation class rather than its ID
- you must not use quotes around the implementation class

The last two points are described in the Gradle Forums question 
[Cannot apply plugin by id in init.gradle script](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/cannot-apply-plugin-by-id-in-init-gradle-script/30377/2).

### How to Find the Implementation Class

If you wonder what the implementation class is for your plugin, here's how I found it for the Gradle Test Logger Plugin:

- Open the project on github
- Look at it's build.gradle file
- Look for the section `gradlePlugin {`
- Take the value from `implementationClass`

  - for example: https://github.com/radarsh/gradle-test-logger-plugin/blob/29af9282761f003f51d49aa804cc72e35b16c33b/build.gradle#L61
- Remember to *not* copy the quotes :)

Answer (score -1):

You could create a `build.gradle` in [buildSrc](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec%3abuild_sources) which implements your custom logic. Just don't check it into version control. To apply it to multiple projects you could create a central `buildSrc` directory and create symbolic links in  the projects that you want to apply it to.