# Permanently add a plugin to Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I use a third-party Gradle plugin in a lot of projects and would like to add this plugin permanently to my gradle installation. Currently I need to add the plugin to each build.gradle like so:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to add this plugin to my Gradle installation so that I don't need to include it in every build file?

I do realise it might not be the best practice and can result in unreproducible builds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global Plugins in Gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567786/global-plugins-in-gradle)

Comment: @saberduck maybe, not sure. does `buildscript {` work in `init.gradle`?

Comment: I never tried it, but I don't see a reason why not

Comment: @saberduck It gives an error: `A problem occurred evaluating initialization script. Cannot change configuration 'classpath' after it has been resolved`

Comment: can you try to replace buildscript with initscript? As here https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:custom_classpath

Comment: Tried the initscript. With some `println` can see it being invoked but still gradle complains that it can't find the plugin.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567786/global-plugins-in-gradle . Answer is from Gradle founder.

Answer (score 4):

**This is a hack and not a solution**

Here is now an updated version which is also able to apply plugins and add maven repositories. Testet with gradle 2.10.

Add this Plugin to your .gradle/init.gradle:

```
apply plugin:AddDepPlugin

class AddDepPlugin  implements Plugin<Gradle> {
    def addDeps = [
        "org.ensime.gradle": "gradle.plugin.net.coacoas.gradle:ensime-gradle:0.2.2",
        "com.github.dcendents.android-maven": "com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2"] 
    def addRepos = ["https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"]
    void apply(Gradle gradle) {
        def add = 0
        gradle.allprojects { project ->
            plugins.whenPluginAdded { t ->
                if (++add == 1) {
                    project.getBuildScriptSource()
                    def bs = project.getBuildscript()
                    bs.getDependencies()
                    def repo = bs.getRepositories()
                    def ccf = bs.class.getDeclaredField("classpathConfiguration")
                    ccf.setAccessible(true)
                    def cc = ccf.get(bs)
                    addDeps.each { k,v-> cc.dependencies.add(project.dependencies.create(v))}
                    addRepos.each { k-> repo.maven { -> setUrl(k) } }
                }
                if (add == 8)
                    addDeps.each { k,v ->
                        if (!k.startsWith("x")) project.apply([plugin: k])
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using this to add the ensime gradle plugin, but it gives: "Task 'ensime' not found in root project 'shared-scala'."

Comment: adding and apply is different - I updated the snippet

Comment: What does the `add==8` section do?

Comment: ensures that the built-in plugins are loaded/applied first before the here-in defined plugins are loaded/applied

Answer (score 1):

On http://ensime.github.io//build_tools/gradle/ I found this alternative solution (this is for the ENSIME plugin):

```
apply plugin: AddEnsimePlugin

class AddEnsimePlugin  implements Plugin<Gradle> {
  def supportedPlugins = [
    'org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin',
    'org.gradle.api.plugins.ScalaPlugin',
    'jp.leafytree.gradle.AndroidScalaPlugin'
  ]

  void apply(Gradle gradle) {
    def added = false

    gradle.allprojects { project ->
      project.with { 
        if (parent == null) {
          buildscript { 
            repositories {
              jcenter()
              maven {
                name 'JFrog OSS Snapshot Repository'
                url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/oss-snapshot-local'
              }
            }
            dependencies {
              classpath 'net.coacoas.gradle:ensime-gradle:0.2.6'
            }
          }
        }

        plugins.whenPluginAdded { plugin ->
          if (!added && supportedPlugins.contains(plugin.class.name)) { 
            rootProject.apply plugin: 'org.ensime.gradle'
            added = true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works for me with Gradle 2.12. The other answer also works for me.